# Conditional return type based on argument type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to define a generic function type named Callbackify in Typescript that does the following things:

- If the given argument is undefined, return a promise of given generic type E
- If the given argument is a callback function, return void

I want to use it as a return type for this callbackify function:

```
function callbackify<E>(executor: () => Promise<E>):  Callbackify<E> {
   // omitted implementation
}
```

A few use cases of the function would be:

```
const fn = callbackify(() => Promise.resolve(4));

// given a callback function as an argument, so should return void
let returnValue = fn((err, value) => { console.log(err, value) })
typeof returnValue // void

//given no argument, so should return Promise<number>
let returnValue = fn()
typeof returnValue // Promise<number>
```

I have tried the following way but it does not seem to work as expected (it always returns void)

```
export type CallbackFunction<T> = (error: Error | null, value?: T) => void;
export type Callbackify<T extends CallbackFunction<E>> = (done?: T) => T extends undefined | null ? Promise<E> : void;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use overloads. Overloads are a better match for what you are trying to do:

```
export type CallbackFunction<T> = (error: Error | null, value?: T) => void;
export type Callbackify<E> = {
    (done: CallbackFunction<E>): void;
    (): Promise<E>;
}

function callbackify<E>(executor: () => Promise<E>): Callbackify<E> { // Explicit return type not really necesarry 
    function callbackified(done: CallbackFunction<E>): void;
    function callbackified(): Promise<E>;
    function callbackified(done?: CallbackFunction<E>): Promise<E> | void {
        return null!
    }
    return callbackified;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBhAhgGxwIywGMBrAMQFcA7IuASyioB4AVAPgQF4EAKEGGLABcCAKIDYCAD4IqFPABoEAN1wUQAfhEsAlFw7KodACYBuUJFiIUaTLgLESdAGbImojtwDewBH97GjCAi2HiEpJQ09IzubDoihibm-rzxCAAKggC2dADOILHmAL7AwM7UtAxUCET24U6usXxgIEQUcMKp+hnZeQUeaaEOpC5uHgheCAD0U2KQOHREdIgwIHAUMNU26FRQKyD2yLKtILlYAke+-uVRVTV1ji50IMY8gVTBdmGOkZUxAwkjGYrn4bn9qrVviNnM9XmlMlAcvlCiCEGDohCHtDYW8glovsNyBUMbF4b1keMZIljBNUSlVutNrJ5DgAISokr0tYbTFQhqw4qlYBERi5RDOarcSGE0Y8Hh6TgcBFIkAAOlWuSgOGUIB4ABYdDpzMAZggAOZ0HXVLD3Plo4l3LC5BBYa0wM0ULIgKhwJSahC5AAWUHkNIZPJUQOAODWCHDmwAamp0NwJXL+DAlKocOoFRxJiKqJqY6qcFAzXwBFnk3oijpgNsoM449zE8nprNqUKY-tGVQkzmQMq+lw0VR5UKgA)